# State conversion from cartesian to spherical

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, kalman-filter

I am looking for a general transformation matrix to convert a state vector from spherical coordinates to cartesian.

$$\begin{bmatrix}r \\ \theta \\ \phi \\ \dot{r} \\ \dot{\theta} \\ \dot{\phi} \end{bmatrix} = A \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{z} \end{bmatrix}$$

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#From_Cartesian_coordinates_2)
shows the transformation from $ (x, y, z)\rightarrow (r,\theta,\phi)$

and [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) (equation 97) shows the transformation from $ (\dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z})\rightarrow  (\dot{r}, \dot{\theta}, \dot{\phi})$

lets say 
$$\begin{bmatrix}r \\ \theta \\ \phi \end{bmatrix} = B \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$$ and 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{r} \\ \dot{\theta} \\ \dot{\phi} \end{bmatrix} = C \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{z} \end{bmatrix}$$

could I also say this?

$$\begin{bmatrix}r \\ \theta \\ \phi \\ \dot{r} \\ \dot{\theta} \\ \dot{\phi} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{Bmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & C\end{Bmatrix}
 \cdot  \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \\ \dot{z} \end{bmatrix}$$

I'm currently trying to create a transformation matrix for a Kalman filter that takes spherical sensor data to best estimate the position and velocity of an object and I'm asking this to create an H matrix. Currently using [this](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/) source as a guide.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This transformation is **not** linear, i.e. cannot be written as matrix $\cdot$ vector